# How to align two elements in the same line in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage in which at the top there are two elements, one is homepage logo and the other is upload button. The upload button (upload button should be  little bit more on the top) at this moment is not aligned in a straight line with the homepage logo.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tekm6f0e/embedded/result/).

The HTML and CSS codes for the homepage logo and the button are:

HTML:

```
<div id="upload-button">
    <ul id="horizontal-list">
        <li class="homepage-logo">
            <a href="https://www.homesail.ca/prelaunch" target="_blank">
                <img src="assets/img/Uploads/logofinalhomesail.png">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="upload-button">Upload</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* homepage logo + Upload-button start */

#upload-button {
    display: table;
}

#horizontal-list {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#horizontal-list .homepage-logo {
    margin-left: 540px;
}


/* homepage logo + Upload-button finish */
```

I am wondering, how I can put the homepage logo and upload button properly aligned (with upload button little bit on the top). I did make a separate class in html for upload button but unfortunately still in CSS, I am not able to align both of them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Top:**

```
ul li:last-child {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
#upload-button {
    display: table;
}

#horizontal-list {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#horizontal-list .homepage-logo {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul li:last-child {
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="upload-button">
    <ul id="horizontal-list">
        <li class="homepage-logo">
            <a href="https://www.homesail.ca/prelaunch" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="upload-button">Upload</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**For Middle :**

```
ul li a img{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
#upload-button {
    display: table;
}

#horizontal-list {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#horizontal-list .homepage-logo {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul li a img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:50px;

}
```

```html
<div id="upload-button">
    <ul id="horizontal-list">
        <li class="homepage-logo">
            <a href="https://www.homesail.ca/prelaunch" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="upload-button">Upload</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but it is going at the top. I just want upload text to be in the middle of logo.

Comment: It did work. Thanks. Also, I am wondering, how can I adjust the movement of  text ? (I can see that margin-top and margin-bottom not working, Is there any way we can make them work ?)

Comment: @flash , you are welcome! Give me more explanation please.

Comment: like with margin-top and margin-bottom, we can adjust the movement of text  . Why here margin-top and margin-bottom not working ?

Comment: `margin-top` (and `margin-bottom`) property sets the top(bottom) margin of an element and dont work here,best way is use of `vertical-align`.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle one more time. Here is my [updated fiddle.]  (https://jsfiddle.net/yh4oncxs/5/embedded/result/)

At this moment again it is not properly aligned. I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the current CSS in order for the logo and the upload button to remain in the same line. The CSS for the upload button and homepage logo is:

**.top {
    display: inline;
}

.homepage-logo {
    text-align: center;
}

.upload-button {
    text-align: right;
}**

Comment: For some reasons, I want to use the current HTML & CSS codes for the proper alignment of the logo and the upload button.

Answer (score 1):

Just go with **flex** container modern way

```
#horizontal-list{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yh4oncxs/2)***

Comment: Here is [update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh4oncxs/5/embedded/result/) I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the current CSS codes for the proper alignment of the logo and the upload button.

For some reasons, I want to use the current HTML & CSS codes for the proper alignment of the logo and the upload button.

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
 ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline;

}
```

to following

```
ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I centered the "Upload" with the logo on its left and centered the logo&upload horizontally.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #4676f2;
}


/* homepage logo + Upload-button start */

#upload-button {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

#horizontal-list {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#horizontal-list .homepage-logo {
    margin-left: 540px;
}


/* homepage logo + Upload-button finish */


/* search box start */

#myInput {
    background-image: url(../assets/img/Uploads/searchicon.png);
    background-position: 99% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 670px;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}


/* search box finish */


/* search box dropdown start */

#myUL {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#myUL li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: -1px;
    /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    display: block
}

#myUL li a.header {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee;
}


/* search box dropdown finish */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Search Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/Uploads/favicon.png">

</head>

<body>


    <div id="upload-button">
        <ul id="horizontal-list">
            <li class="homepage-logo">
                <a href="https://www.homesail.ca/prelaunch" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://s9.postimg.org/4xgk9tban/logofinalhomesail.png">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="upload-button">Upload</li>
        </ul>
    </div>






    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a name">

    <ul id="myUL">
        <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" class="header">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">F</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" class="header">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">J</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
            li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";

                }
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```